# Federated with Auth0 not working in Amplify React

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, auth0, aws-amplify

I'm following this documentation: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication in the Federated with Auth0 section, and I'm trying to set up Auth0 sign in through my Congito React login component. 
[image: login component]

However I get this error as soon as the login renders:

[ERROR] 42:27.234 AuthError - 
Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly. 
The configuration object is missing required auth properties. 
Did you run `amplify push` after adding auth via `amplify add auth`?
See https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#amplify-project-setup for more information

I did run amplify auth and then amplify push, and if I run push again it says there are no changes to be made

this is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import { withAuthenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react';
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

// auth0 configuration, more info in: https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js/v9#available-parameters
Auth.configure({
    auth0: {
        domain: <MY DOMAIN>.auth0.com, 
        clientID: <AUTH0 CLIENT ID>,
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/',
        audience: 'https://<MY DOMAIN>.auth0.com/userinfo',
        responseType: 'token id_token', 
        scope: 'openid profile email',
        returnTo: 'http://localhost:3000/'
    }
});


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withAuthenticator(App);
```

does anyone know what the issue could be?

Answer (score 1):

I work with the Auth0 Community. Looking at this it appears this is related to amplify as the `[ERROR] 42:27.234 AuthError - Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly.` error suggests. Although I don't know the exact error breakdown, it does help give a place to build on.

I did find this open github issue that produced a similar error: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/4315

Comment: The issue says to update to amplify 2.2.0, but I am already on that version. Will follow that issue though

Answer (score 0):

The options you're passing to Amplify don't look correct. I think you should be using the ones from [the Amplify docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/start/q/platform/js/#re-use-existing-authentication-resource). If you're using Amplify CLI (which you are if you've run `amplify push`), then you should have an `aws-exports.js` file which declares an object which you should be passing to `Amplify.configure()` as described in the [Getting Started section](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/js/#configure-your-application).